# Use input redirection from a text file using BASH to use as data in a C program

Tags: c, bash

I need to gather data written in a text file and use a bash shell which will allow each line of the text file to be used in my c program as separate data points. For a little more context, my program is taking in a set of coordinates(x,y) for as many lines there are in my input.txt file. After that, it will find the nearest and furthest points in reference to the one it is on.

For example input.txt has the following lines:

```
    input1 3.2 9.3
    input2 5.7 13.6
    input3 18.4 12.2
```

I have not found out how to do this on bash. I have written the following program to do something very similar but not dynamically using bash redirection.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct coordinates{
    //The label of the coordinates
    char coordinateName[32];
    //The x and y coordinates
    float xCoord;
    float yCoord;

} coordinate;

//Function to calculate distance from another point
float distance(char p1[32], char p2[32], float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2){
    float c;

    c = sqrt( pow((x1-x2),2) + pow((y1-y2),2) );

    printf("\nDistance between %s and %s is: \t\t\t\t%.2f", p1, p2, c);
    return c;
}

int main () {
    // Get the number of inputs being taken in from the user via command line
    char ENTRIESstring[1]; 
    int ENTRIES;

    scanf("%s", ENTRIESstring);
    ENTRIES = atoi(ENTRIESstring);
    // Declare a struct object
    struct coordinates myCoordinates[ENTRIES];

    for(int i = 0; i<ENTRIES; i++){
        // Enter the coordinate name
        //printf("Enter a Coordinate name: ");
        scanf("%s", &*myCoordinates[i].coordinateName);
        // Ask for x coordinate
        //printf("Enter a Coordinate value for x: ");
        scanf("%f", &myCoordinates[i].xCoord);
        // Ask for y coordinate
        //printf("Enter a Coordinate value for y: ");
        scanf("%f", &myCoordinates[i].yCoord);
    }

    //define closest and furthest points
    float closestPoints = INFINITY, furthestPoints = 0.0;
    int closestPoint1, closestPoint2;
    int furthestPoint1, furthestPoint2;
    //define calculation variable to check against closest and furthest point
    float calculation;

    for(int i = 0; i <= ENTRIES-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= ENTRIES-1; j++) {

            char *p1,*p2;
            float x1,x2,y1,y2;

            p1 = myCoordinates[i].coordinateName;
            x1 = myCoordinates[i].xCoord;
            y1 = myCoordinates[i].yCoord;
            p2 = myCoordinates[j].coordinateName;
            x2 = myCoordinates[j].xCoord;
            y2 = myCoordinates[j].yCoord;
            
            //if coord1 is equal to coord2 skip
            if(i==j){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                printf("\n%s - (x:%.2f,y:%.2f) and %s - (x:%.2f,y:%.2f)", p1,x1,y1,p2,x2,y2);

                calculation = distance(p1, p2, x1, x2, y1, y2);

                if (calculation < closestPoints){
                    closestPoint1 = i;
                    closestPoint2 = j;
                    closestPoints = calculation;
                }
                else if (calculation > furthestPoints){
                    furthestPoint1 = i;
                    furthestPoint2 = j;
                    furthestPoints = calculation;
                }
                printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nClosest points:  point %s and point %s - distance:  \t%.2f", myCoordinates[closestPoint1].coordinateName, myCoordinates[closestPoint2].coordinateName, closestPoints);
    printf("\nFurthest points: point %s and point %s - distance: \t%.2f\n", myCoordinates[furthestPoint1].coordinateName, myCoordinates[furthestPoint2].coordinateName, furthestPoints);
    return(0);
}
```

Any insight or sources to read on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For reading from a file connected to standard input, you don't really want the prompts.  You run the program `./program < input.txt` and the shell takes care of the I/O redirection.  Your program simply reads from standard input and does its stuff.  On POSIX-like systems, you can use `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` to find out whether the input is a terminal and avoid prompting if it is not.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that much. When the file input gets redirected, each line gets assigned what is each line considered as in the program?

Comment: When you use `scanf()`, it really doesn't care about lines.  It will read three values (name, x, y) in turn.  With the input file shown, it will start on a new line every three entries, but you could have the whole file on a single line, or each item on a separate line with random numbers of blank lines in between and it would all work the same.  An alternative is to rewrite the code so it uses `fgets()` or an equivalent to read a line and you can then use `sscanf()` or other tools to parse that line of data.  There are some advantages to that technique (especially when reporting errors).

Comment: The redirection just enters the data in the file as if it were keystrokes from a keyboard.  The data ends up wherever it would end up if you were entering it from the keyboard.  If you do want to see individual lines coming in use `getline()` and then use `sscanf()` to get the data out of the variable that holds the line.

Comment: Is it really that easy? So I would just take out the prompting and with each null character it assumes that the next item being read in is the variable I am looking for?

Comment: Yup, it really is that easy.  It's one of the reasons Unix and derivative systems are so powerful. (I'm not quite sure where null characters (null bytes, `'\0'`) figure in the discussion.  You're reading text files and text files don't contain null bytes in single-byte code sets — or in UTF-8.)

Comment: Ok thought it would be more complicated. What tells me how many lines are in the text file? Assuming I need to know this because I need to figure out how many objects to create. And would this be the same with output redirection? After I am done with the calculations I am supposed to use redirection to send it to a text file

Comment: What would the BASH script look like?

Comment: If you use `fgets()` or equivalent to read lines, then you count how many times you call it before reaching EOF to determine the number of lines in the file.  With `scanf()`, there isn't a reliable way to count physical lines (because `scanf()` skips white space, including newlines, willy-nilly).  You can make assumptions and count the number of times you read three entries and assume each set of three is one input line.  You can do various tricks to avoid too much memory allocation.  One is to allocate, say, 16 objects, and then when you read a 17th one, reallocate the space (double it)…

Comment: The Bash script would look like the command line I showed in my first comment, give or take a shebang line, comments, and maybe an `exec` in front of the command.  You might decide to use `$PATH` to find the program rather than relying on the executable being in the current directory, hence: `exec program < input.txt`.  Or maybe `cat "$@" | program`.  Or you could write the program so that it reads from files named on the command line (like `cat` does), or reads from standard input if no files are specified.  That's a common Unix idiom — the program becomes a filter.

Comment: And if the program is a filter, the Bash script becomes largely irrlevant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So turns out I was on the money but using wrong syntax lol sorry I was under the impression I needed to figure out how to use BASH scripting(#!/bin/bash) and for redirection I was using the ">" into input.txt instead of < into "input.txt". Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Your C program is bound to crash: `scanf("%s", ENTRIESstring)` reads the next input word (up to the next white space), but the receiving array `ENTRIESstring` has only the length 1. Since `scanf` places a terminating NUL character after the text being read, it would at the very least require an array of length two. As a general rule, don't ever use `scanf` except for reading from files where you have complete control over their content, and even then, don't forget to provide space for the extra NUL character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the C code is compiled to an executable `a.out`, would you
please try the bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out $(wc -l < input.txt) < input.txt > output,txt
```

- `$(wc -l < input.txt)` counts the lines of the input file and
  is passed to `a.out` as the 1st argument.
- The `input.txt` is redirecred to the standard input of `a.out`
  and the output is redirected to `output.txt`, which is created as a new file.

The C code will work without modifications but may be refined
e.g. removing the prompts.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for showing me the syntax on how this works. I removed all of the prompts and this works just fine.